# ReactJS - How detect if an element is the nth _ first _ or last child of its parent in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make some dynamic moves in ReactJS hence I need to check the child-position relatively to its parent, how can I detect it in ReactJS, please?

I have seen [this post](https://mxstbr.blog/2017/02/react-children-deepdive/#function-as-a-child) but it is for the detection between components, no inside a specific component as follow for example:

```
<div
className={style.carousel}
>
     <div 
         id={style.carousel_item_one}
     > 
              carousel_item_1 // => first child, but how detect it?

     </div>
     <div 
         id={style.carousel_item_two}
     > 
              carousel_item_2 // => nth child, but how detect it?
     </div>
     <div 
         id={style.carousel_item_three}
     > 
              carousel_item_3 // => last child, but how detect it?
     </div>
</div>
```

Any hint would be great,

thanks

Comment: Where are you doing these checks and what happens when you do? You might think about having each of those as components mapped from an array, passing in the index of the array, and the array length to do those calculations.

Comment: effectively thanks, it is for trigger different animations, I'm check after onClick on the element

Answer (score 1):

OK. Here's how I would approach this (in line with my comment). In short use an array of objects to describe your carousel panels, and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over it, creating a new panel with each iteration. Each panel has data attributes attached to it that describe the current panel index and the array length. These can then be use in the click handler as part of a calculation.

```js
class Carousel extends React.Component {
  
  constructor() {
    super();

    // Make sure you bind your handler
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {

    // Destruct the id and length from the target dataset
    const { dataset: { id, length } } = e.target;

    // Here you would perform your calculation
    console.log(id, length);
  }

  render() {

    // Get the panel data we passed in
    const { panels } = this.props;

    // Grab the length of the panel array
    const { length } = panels;

    // `map` over the panels array to create a new panel with each
    // iteration. Note we also use `map`'s index parameter 
    return panels.map((panel, index) => {

      // Add the index, length as element data attributes
      return (
        <div
          key={index}
          data-id={index}
          data-length={length}
          className="carouselItem"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          >
          {panel.desc} ({index} of {panels.length})
        </div>
      );
    });  
  }
}

// Panel data
const panels = [{ desc: 'Panel 1' }, { desc: 'Panel 2' }, { desc: 'Panel 3' }];

ReactDOM.render(

  // Pass in the panel data as props
  <Carousel panels={panels} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.carouselItem {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding: 0.3em;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}

.carouselItem:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```